# Check if a button is clicked on an activity on first launch android

Tags: java, android

I have this code that if an app is launched the first time. If it is launched the first time, it displays the Register activity then on second launch it displays the MainAcitivity.

```
Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
        if (isFirstRun) {

            startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class));
            //Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Authenticated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();
            //finish the application after first run
            finish();
        }
        {
        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", true).commit();
           // finish();
        }
```

The above code works fine but if the user did not click the button in the register activity and launches the app once again, it takes the user to MainActivity thereby the user did not register but making use of the app. How can I check that the button in the register activity is clicked on first launch and if not navigate the user back to the register activity.

**xml for user registration**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Username"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:text="Phone No" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
        android:text="Register" />
```

**updated code**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.register) {


//          if(!validate()){
            // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
            new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://xyz/create");
            //new AttemptRegistration().execute();
//          }

            Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
            if (isFirstRun) {
                //show start activity

                startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class));
                //Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Authenticated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();
                //finish the application after first run
                finish();
            }
            {
            getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", true).commit();
               // finish();
            }

        }
```

Is there a way I can place a check that the button in the register activity is clicked

Comment: You need to put 'true' in your SharedPreferences in RegisterActivity on button click

Comment: Add button onclickListener, google how to do it and in `onClick` method set  your boolean to **false** since it's not the first run anymore.

Comment: I have actually updated my code with the onClick listener and the boolean set to false

Comment: But since this code is within an event it will always be effective when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Instead of saving your `isFirstRun` boolean when the app opens, save it when the registration button is clicked. Just move the logic into the registration button's `onClick` method. However, you still need to check for the boolean in the `onCreate` method of your `Register` activity. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ....

    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
    if (isFirstRun) {
        //show start activity

        startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class));
        //Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Authenticated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();
        //finish the application after first run
        finish();
    }
    // .....

}
```

Then, in your `onClick`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", true).commit();
// ...
}
```

Comment: With the above everytime I launches it, it displays the registration activity. But I want it to be displayed only once when the user clicks the register button of this activity. Do I update my question with the code

Comment: @Blaze - code example is updated. Let me know if you have any other questions